# How to get all urls from a webpage belonging to same Domain

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, web-scraping

Currently i am using this code to get the above :

```
                     Uri baseUri = new Uri(url);
                    Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, strRef);
                    domain = baseUri.Host;

                    Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
                    strRef = myUri.ToString();
                    if (strRef.Contains(domain))
                    {
                     //THIS MEANS IT BELONGS TO SAME DOMAIN...
                    }
```

But using this code i am having some issue like suppose we have a main url = **http://www.xxx.co.uk**
Then the above code also treats a url like **http://www.news.xxx.co.uk** as external link ? Is this correct should it do that if not any one know a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are in the correct path. But, to grab the latter mentioned URL (http://www.news.xxx.co.uk/) you could do a quick fix like this.

```
domain = baseUri.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty);
```

Cheers!

vote if helpful.